# Getting the vertices of UTM grid in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinates, utm, point-creation

I've downloaded from [the official repository](https://www.miteco.gob.es/es/biodiversidad/servicios/banco-datos-naturaleza/malla_5x5_tierra_p_tcm30-508790.zip) the UTM 5x5 km grid of Spain and uploaded it to a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database (vv. 14 & 3.1.4).

I need to obtain the coordinates of every cell vertices, but my attempts using `st_dumppoints()` return more than 4 points for each one:

```
select path, ST_AsText(geom) from (
select (st_dumppoints(geom)).* from referencia.malla_5x5_p) a

{1,1}   "POINT(158179.43709999975 4135320.7804000005)"
{1,2}   "POINT(158147.76989999972 4134822.7887999993)"
{1,3}   "POINT(158144.77589999977 4134822.9791)"
{1,4}   "POINT(158125.79449999984 4134824.1861000005)"
{1,5}   "POINT(157646.78249999974 4134854.6448999997)"
{1,6}   "POINT(157627.35280000046 4134855.8804)"
[...]
```

Thanks to the excellent contribution of @geozelot, I now know that I can't get the "four" vertices of each polygon. So let's put my question this other way: how could I get the intersection points of the UTM grid?

Comment: UTM cells follow the curvature of the given ellipsoid, which is expressed in the data as a varying density of vertices per cell. I.e. these cells are no rectangles, and thus cannot simply be constructed with 4 corners (note that a valid polygon has n + 1 vertices to close the boundary on itself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To extract the contextual *corner points* of each cell, find those vertices that have an angle greater than *roughly* `90°` with respect to the preceding and following vertex:

```
SELECT
  utm_c.[*],  -- list needed columns explicitly and exclude the geom column
  pts.geom
FROM 
  <utm_cells> AS utm_c
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      dmp.geom,
      ST_Angle(
        LAG(dmp.geom) OVER w,
        dmp.geom,
        COALESCE(LEAD(dmp.geom) OVER w, NTH_VALUE(dmp.geom, 2) OVER w)
      )::INT AS _a
    FROM
      ST_DumpPoints(utm_c.geom) AS dmp
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id, dmp.path[1:2] ORDER BY dmp.path[3])
  ) AS pts
WHERE
  _a > 3
;
```

*Note that this assumes the cell geometries to be `MULTIPOLYGONS`; if this is not the case, use:*

```
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id, dmp.path[1] ORDER BY dmp.path[2])
```

*instead!*

Here, `_a` is the angle in *radians* - rounded down to the nearest integer - between each triplet of vertices, with `3` corresponding to angles greater than `~229.18°`.

The result set contains respective *corners* for **every** cell, not singular intersection points - you can filter the set with `GROUP BY geom`, but you loose *individual* cell information.

Comment: That's a pretty neat query! One thing, though: the data in question seems to be vectorized pixels, having tiny 'steps' on non-aligned cell borders. Wouldn't this approach fail to exclude them if the 'steps' are at right angles, too?

Comment: @t.ry indeed. This would require to apply the same logic iteratively until vertex count is constant...